# PHP array_chunk, prevent duplicate chunks

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array of people let's say:

`$a = ['John', 'Amy', 'Bill', 'Jim']`

The array can have much more than 4 elements.

I need to generate 2 pairings for each element with another element in the same array without generating duplicate pairings (where avoidable) or pairing an element with itself:

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => John
        [1] => Amy
    )


[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Amy
        [1] => Bill
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bill
        [1] => Jim
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => John
        [1] => Jim
    )
```

)

I've tried sloppy techniques such as duplicating the array, merging them both, and chunking them into into pairs. Duplicate pairings, and same element pairings kept appearing though, so I've tried stuff like `shuffle($duplicated_array)` and `array_reverse($duplicated_array)` before merging and chunking the array, still duplicate pairings can still exist.

What is the proper way to generate 2 pairings for each element in an array without creating duplicate pairings or pairing an element with itself?

Thanks in advance.

here is an example of an attempt that does not quite prevent duplicates:

```
$duplicate_array = $a;
        shuffle($duplicate_array);
        $combined = array_merge($duplicate_array, $a);
        $combined = array_chunk($combined,2);
```

Comment: IS the array you show us the result you are trying to achieve or the one you got that is not what you want

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for a bit of help with your homework. Beginners are welcome, but we expect a good faith attempt at an answer from you first. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @RiggsFolly the array I show is one possible example of what I want to achieve: an array with two pairings for each element, with no duplicate pairings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make 2 loops and a simple check if names are the same.

```
<?php
$arr = ['John', 'Amy', 'Bill', 'Jim'];

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    foreach ($arr as $b) {
        if ($a === $b) continue;
        $result[] = [$a, $b];
    } 
}

print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Amy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Bill
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Jim
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amy
            [1] => John
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amy
            [1] => Bill
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amy
            [1] => Jim
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bill
            [1] => John
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bill
            [1] => Amy
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bill
            [1] => Jim
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jim
            [1] => John
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jim
            [1] => Amy
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jim
            [1] => Bill
        )

)
```

Want a middle name, add 3 loops and so on.

```
<?php
$arr = ['John', 'Amy', 'Bill', 'Jim'];

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    foreach ($arr as $b) {
        if ($a === $b) continue;
        foreach ($arr as $c) {
            if ($a === $c || $b === $c) continue;
            $result[] = [$a, $b, $c];
        }
    } 
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pair each name with the following name in the array.

```
$names = ['John', 'Amy', 'Bill', 'Jim'];

$n = count($names);
foreach ($names as $index => $name) {
    $pairs[] = [$name, $names[($index + 1) % $n]];
}
```

If the pairs need to be randomized, you can shuffle the names before you do the the pairing.